Error during installation of Ruby on Rails
rails installation failed on Macbookair because of "Invalid IP Address" or issue with access privileges
I have installed JRuby 9.2.9.0 on the MacBook Air.
When I was trying to install the rails using the command:
"jruby -S gem install rails"
I get a not able to access site sun.nio.ch
and an invalid IP Address error.
How can I fix it. Please help.
=============================Logging Error Message===================
sathyadevarakonda@192 homebrew % which jruby
/Users/sathyadevarakonda/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.9.0/bin/jruby
sathyadevarakonda@192 homebrew % jruby -S gem install rails
2024-09-23T11:59:25.699+05:30 [main] WARN FilenoUtil : Native subprocess control requires open access to sun.nio.ch
Pass '--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=org.jruby.dist' or '=org.jruby.core' to enable.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (IPAddr::InvalidAddressError)
invalid address
sathyadevarakonda@192 homebrew %

what you need to do is:
adding this code to the end of your ~/.zshrc
export JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=org.jruby.dist"

using nano ~/.zshrc or you favorite text editor
and this should fix your problem.
and then putting source ~/.zshrc for the updates to work

Adding export JAVA_OPTS to a rc file (.zshrc) would require opening a new terminal, or calling source ~/.zshrc to take effect. I suggest you update your answer, or you risk newcommers thinking it's not working.

I tried this one sir:
export JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" and it worked. But the IPAddress error is still there - I am working on that - Thank you

@satya-devarakonda Glad to help!

@Greg i edited my answer to include that.

@satya-devarakonda don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

I used homebrew to download things. These were located at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/. So I added the following path to my .zshrc where the gem executable is located in the Cellar area i.e. /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.5/bin.
Then %sudo gem install rails worked.

For those of us who are new to on Ruby On Rails:
The previous answer was installing Ruby and Rails using rvm. Later I tried using rbenv on my mac and it works great and better. Thank you
What is Ruby - As there are so many programming languages Ruby is a programming language that is generally used to create web services.
What is a framework? A framework is a tool to create a project and all the basic set of classes, files, and configuration details for the web application by running a single command.
What is Rails - Rails is an application framework, like the Microsoft Foundation Classes Framework, that builds and as well hosts the expected web service using a built-in application server like tomcat for springboot.
Now, there are versions of Ruby, and there are versions of Rails.
rvm is a manager that can help install versions of Ruby and Rails. JRuby is another version of Ruby from Oracle Corp.
rbenv is another tool that can be used to install Ruby and Rails.
Homebrew is a software generally used on Mac that installs and points to different versions of tools, and links hosted on GitHub, which are not built into the Mac’s existing Operating System. rvm is generally more involved than rbenv.
Instead of using rvm, you can also use HomeBrew and rbenv to install rails on a Mac. Try to install Homebrew on Mac and install Jruby from Homebrew. There are different versions of Ruby generally, and you can use any Ruby to start writing your code(you may need an editor, though).
I used rbenv by running the homebrew command(on Mac) to download rbenv, and everything was working perfectly well. Try it instead of fighting with rvm. rvm is a little complicated.

Please reduce your answer to the parts that are really relevant to resolve the initial problem
